# Not able to create Azure Web App Bot, getting Authentication error

Tags: azure, chatbot

Not able to create Azure Web App Boat.

I am getting below error while creating:

**Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.**

Comment: I am using free trial account for the same...

Comment: Are you the owner of the azure subscription? What is the remaining credit of your subscription?